# Python: Extending a predefined named tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, namedtuple

I have the following named tuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
ReadElement = namedtuple('ReadElement', 'address value')
```

and then I want the following:

```
LookupElement = namedtuple('LookupElement', 'address value lookups')
```

There is duplication between the two namedtuples, how can I subclass ReadElement to contain an additional field?

```
class LookupElement(ReadElement):
    def __new__(self, address, value, lookups):
        self = super(LookupElement, self).__new__(address, value)
        l = list(self)
        l.append(lookups)
        return tuple(l)
```

However the tuple is created there an then in the **new** statement, if I modify self to be a list I will loose type information, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can subclass a `namedtuple`-produced class, but you need to study the generated class more closely. You'll need to add another `__slots__` attribute with the extra fields, update the `_fields` attribute, create new `__repr__` and `_replace` methods (they hardcode the field list and class name) and add extra `property` objects for the additional fields. See the [example in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

That's all a little too much work. Rather than subclass, I'd just reuse the [`somenamedtuple._fields` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields) of the source type:

```
LookupElement = namedtuple('LookupElement', ReadElement._fields + ('lookups',))
```

The `field_names` argument to the `namedtuple()` constructor doesn't have to be a string, it can also be a sequence of strings. Simply take the `_fields` and add more elements by concatenating a new tuple.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> ReadElement = namedtuple('ReadElement', 'address value')
>>> LookupElement = namedtuple('LookupElement', ReadElement._fields + ('lookups',))
>>> LookupElement._fields
('address', 'value', 'lookups')
>>> LookupElement('addr', 'val', 'lookup') 
LookupElement(address='addr', value='val', lookups='lookup')
```

This does mean that the extended type is not a subclass of the base type. If you must have a class hierarchy, then rather than try to make named tuples fit that model, I'd switch to using [*dataclasses*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes) instead. Dataclasses can serve the same purpose in most usecases named tuples are used for, but can easily be subclassed.

Comment: This is what the docs suggest doing, but what if you've got a custom namedtuple with a generated field?

Comment: @Ethereal: all namedtuple classes are custom. The `_fields` attribute will still reflect the actual fields on the class.

Comment: I'm finding that this is not true, _fields doesn't contain the generated field! See eg the `hypot` example in the docs.

Comment: @Ethereal so you are talking about a `property` object. I’d never call that a generated field. No, additional attributes on a subclass of a `namedtuple` object are not reflected in the `_fields` attribute. If you need to share additional methods or properties, consider putting those on a mix-in class instead and reuse these between multiple namedtuple classes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters correct, sorry for the nomenclature confusion and the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Extending [Martijn Pieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28500620/7262247): there **is** a way to make the new namedtuple class a subclass of the other, without having to hack. Simply create the new `namedtuple` separately, and then use its `__new__` method instead of using `super`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class ReadElement(namedtuple('ReadElement', ('address', 'value'))):
    def compute(self):
        return self.value + 1

_LookupElement = namedtuple('_LookupElement', ReadElement._fields + ('lookups',))

class LookupElement(_LookupElement, ReadElement):
    def __new__(self, address, value, lookups):
        return _LookupElement.__new__(LookupElement, address, value, lookups)

assert issubclass(LookupElement, ReadElement)
l = LookupElement('ad', 1, dict())
assert isinstance(l, ReadElement)
assert l.compute() == 2
```

It seems that this also works without even overriding `__new__` !

```
from collections import namedtuple

class ReadElement(namedtuple('ReadElement', ('address', 'value'))):
    def compute(self):
        return self.value + 1

class LookupElement(namedtuple('LookupElement', ReadElement._fields + ('lookups',)),
                    ReadElement):
    """nothing special to do"""
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

It's quite easy to knock something together that allows you to compose namedtuples from other namedtuples as well as introduce new fields.

```
def extended_namedtuple(name, source_fields):
    assert isinstance(source_fields, list)
    new_type_fields = []
    for f in source_fields:
        try:
            new_type_fields.extend(f._fields)
        except:
            new_type_fields.append(f) 
    return namedtuple(name, new_type_fields) 

# source types
Name = namedtuple('Name', ['first_name', 'last_name'])
Address = namedtuple('Address', ['address_line1', 'city'])
# new type uses source types and adds additional ID field
Customer = extended_namedtuple('Customer', ['ID', Name, Address])
# using the new type
cust1 = Customer(1, 'Banana', 'Man', '29 Acacia Road', 'Nuttytown')
print(cust1)
```

This outputs the following :

```
Customer(ID=1, first_name='Banana', last_name='Man', address_line1='29 Acacia Road', city='Nuttytown')
```