# A way to subclass NamedTuple for purposes of typechecking

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, namedtuple

I have several `namedtuple`s that share some fields. I have a function that accepts these tuples and is guaranteed to only interact with the shared fields. I want to typecheck such code in mypy.

An example of the code would be:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Base(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int


class BaseExtended(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int
    z: str

def DoSomething(tuple: Base):
    return tuple.x + tuple.y

base = Base(3, 4)
base_extended = BaseExtended(5, 6, 'foo')

DoSomething(base)
DoSomething(base_extended)
```

When I run mypy on this code, I get a predictable error:

> mypy_example.py:20: error: Argument 1 to "DoSomething" has incompatible type "BaseExtended"; expected "Base"

Is there no way to structure my code and keep mypy typechecking? I cannot inherit `BaseExtended` from `Base`, since [there's a bug](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/427) in the `NamedTuple` inheritance implementation.

I don't want to use an ugly `Union[Base, BaseExtended]` either, since this breaks when I try to typecheck a `List`, since `List[Union[Base, BaseExtended]]` is not equal to `List[BaseExtended]` due to [some mypy magic about variant/covariant types](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3351).

Should I just abandon the idea?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The way named tuples are constructed make inheritance from `typing.NamedTuple` classes as yet not possible. You'd have to write your own metaclass to extend the `typing.NamedTupleMeta` class to make subclassing work, and even then [the class generated by `collections.namedtuple()` is just not built to extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500524/python-extending-a-predefined-named-tuple/28500620#28500620).

Instead, you want to use the new [`dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html) to define your classes and achieve inheritance:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Base:
    x: int
    y: int

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class BaseExtended(Base):
    z: str
```

The module is new in Python 3.7 but you can [`pip install dataclasses` the backport](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/#description) on Python 3.6.

The above defines two immutable classes with `x` and `y` attributes, with the `BaseExtended` class adding one more attribute. `BaseExtended` is a full subclass of `Base`, so for typing purposes fits the requirements for the `DoSomething()` function.

The classes are not full named tuples, as they don't have a length or support indexing, but that's trivially added by creating a baseclass that inherits from `collections.abc.Sequence`, adding two methods to access fields by index. If you add `order=True` to the `@dataclass()` decorator then your instances become fully orderable the same way (named) tuples are:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

class DataclassSequence(Sequence):
    # make a dataclass tuple-like by accessing fields by index
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return getattr(self, fields(self)[i].name)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(fields(self))

@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class Base(DataclassSequence):
    x: int
    y: int
```

MyPy [will soon support `dataclasses` explicitly](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4792); in version 0.600 you'll get errors still as it doesn't recognise the `dataclasses` module import or that a `__new__` method is generated.

In Python 3.6 and earlier, you can also install the [`attrs` project](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) to achieve the same effects; the above sequence base class looks like this using `attrs`:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
import attr

class AttrsSequence(Sequence):
    # make a dataclass tuple-like by accessing fields by index
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return getattr(self, attr.fields(type(self))[i].name)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(attr.fields(type(self)))

@attr.s(frozen=True, auto_attribs=True)
class Base(AttrsSequence):
    x: int
    y: int
```

`dataclasses` is directly based on `attrs`, with `attrs` providing more functionality; mypy fully supports classes generated with `attrs`.

Comment: I like that NamedTuple have all a _asdict(), is there a parent type for all data classes?

Comment: @Edmondo1984: Dataclasses have the module-level `dataclasses.asdict()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict). You can always mix in a utility class that defines `asdict()` or `_asdict()` or other methods you want to have on your dataclasses.

Answer (score 3):

There is [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) that proposes an extension to type system that will allow structural subtyping (static duck typing). Also runtime implementation of `typing.NamedTuple` will be improved soon, probably in Python 3.6.2 end of June (this will be also backported via `typing` on PyPI).

Comment: Thank you. I guess you don't know of any elegant workarounds that I could use until 3.6.2? If that's the case I'll just accept the answer and move on.

Comment: @wuzwm No, unfortunately I don't know.

Comment: The improvements have yet to materialise, the same issues still apply to Python 3.6.5 and 3.7.0b4.

Comment: Actually the runtime change was abandoned deliberately. It was decided  that named tuples should stay minimalistic,  and for all complex use cases users should use dataclasses.

Comment: @ivanl Unfortunately `dataclass` isn't a one-to-one replacement for `NamedTuple`. Changing my class inheritance to the former resulted in TypeErrors and Uninitialized attribute warnings from Pyre.