# Typechecking with mypy: 'structures' that have common fields

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I have several simple 'structures' that share typed fields. I want to define a function that operates with the assumption of these fields existing and I want to typecheck that with mypy.

There's a closed mypy feature request [#3521](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3521) with a concise example of what I want:

```
class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int
class LabeledPoint(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int
    label: str

def fun(p: Point): ...
fun(LabeledPoint(1, 2, 'test'))  # OK
```

Unfortunately it seems like NamedTuples will not allow such functionality any time seen (see the two closed issues: [#3521](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3521) and [#427](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/427))

I've asked a similar question before ([A way to subclass NamedTuple for purposes of typechecking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287623/a-way-to-subclass-namedtuple-for-purposes-of-typechecking)) and I got a nice response pointing in the direction of [PEP544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/). While 'protocol' described in the PEP544 is a nice idea, it's designed for proper classes and a bit too much for the task of sharing a few fields.

If there are any alternatives to NamedTuples, please tell me.