# What are data classes and how are they different from common classes?

Tags: python, class, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

[PEP 557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) introduces data classes into the Python standard library. It says that by applying the [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) decorator shown below, it will generate "among other things, an `__init__()`".

> ```
> from dataclasses import dataclass
>
> @dataclass
> class InventoryItem:
>     """Class for keeping track of an item in inventory."""
>     name: str
>     unit_price: float
>     quantity_on_hand: int = 0
>
>     def total_cost(self) -> float:
>         return self.unit_price * self.quantity_on_hand
> ```

It also says dataclasses are "mutable namedtuples with default", but I don't understand what this means, nor how data classes are different from common classes.

What are data classes and when is it best to use them?

Comment: Given the extensive content of the PEP, what else could you want to know? `namedtuple`s are immutable and can't have default values for the attributes, whereas data classes are mutable and can have them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Seems reasonable to me that there should be a stackoverflow thread on the subject. Stackoverflow is meant to be an encyclopedia in Q&A format, no? The answer is never "just look on this other website." There shouldn't have been downvotes here.

Comment: There are five threads on how to append an item to a list. One question on `@dataclass` won't cause the site to disintegrate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `namedtuples` CAN have default values. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351032/namedtuple-and-default-values-for-optional-keyword-arguments

Comment: dataclasses are really convenient and it should become a keyword (or part of a class without decoration) in python. . . https://youtube.com/live/0lCIkY32AdI?feature=share

Answer (score 494, accepted):

Data classes are just regular classes that are geared towards storing state, rather than containing a lot of logic. Every time you create a class that mostly consists of attributes, you make a data class.

What the `dataclasses` module does is to make it **easier** to create data classes. It takes care of a lot of boilerplate for you.

This is especially useful when your data class must be hashable; because this requires a `__hash__` method as well as an `__eq__` method. If you add a custom `__repr__` method for ease of debugging, that can become quite verbose:

```
class InventoryItem:
    '''Class for keeping track of an item in inventory.'''
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0

    def __init__(
            self, 
            name: str, 
            unit_price: float,
            quantity_on_hand: int = 0
        ) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.unit_price = unit_price
        self.quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand

    def total_cost(self) -> float:
        return self.unit_price * self.quantity_on_hand
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return (
            'InventoryItem('
            f'name={self.name!r}, unit_price={self.unit_price!r}, '
            f'quantity_on_hand={self.quantity_on_hand!r})'
        )

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash((self.name, self.unit_price, self.quantity_on_hand))

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, InventoryItem):
            return NotImplemented
        return (
            (self.name, self.unit_price, self.quantity_on_hand) == 
            (other.name, other.unit_price, other.quantity_on_hand))
```

With `dataclasses` you can reduce it to:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class InventoryItem:
    '''Class for keeping track of an item in inventory.'''
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0

    def total_cost(self) -> float:
        return self.unit_price * self.quantity_on_hand
```

(Example based on [the PEP example](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/#abstract)).

The same class decorator can also generate comparison methods (`__lt__`, `__gt__`, etc.) and handle immutability.

`namedtuple` classes are also data classes, but are immutable by default (as well as being sequences). `dataclasses` are much more flexible in this regard, and can easily be structured such that they can [fill the same role as a `namedtuple` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287623/a-way-to-subclass-namedtuple-for-purposes-of-typechecking/50369898#50369898).

The PEP was inspired by the [`attrs` project](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/), which can do even more (including slots, validators, converters, metadata, etc.).

If you want to see some examples, I recently used `dataclasses` for several of my [Advent of Code](http://adventofcode.com/) solutions, see the solutions for [day 7](https://github.com/mjpieters/adventofcode/blob/master/2017/Day%2007.ipynb), [day 8](https://github.com/mjpieters/adventofcode/blob/master/2017/Day%2008.ipynb), [day 11](https://github.com/mjpieters/adventofcode/blob/master/2017/Day%2011.ipynb) and [day 20](https://github.com/mjpieters/adventofcode/blob/master/2017/Day%2020.ipynb).

If you want to use `dataclasses` module in Python versions < 3.7, then you could install the [backported module](https://pypi.org/p/dataclasses/) (requires 3.6) or use the `attrs` project mentioned above.

Comment: In the first example do you intentionally hide class members with instance members of the same names? Please help understanding this idiom.

Comment: @VladimirLenin: there are no class attributes, there are only type annotations. See [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), specifically the [*Class and instance variable annotations* section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations).

Comment: @VladimirLenin: the `= 0` default value for `quantity_on_hand` is redundant in the first example and only there to echo the `dataclasses` example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just to clarify, did you mean "There is only one class attribute, namely `quantity_on_hand` and I do hide it by a instance attribute, but I only chose this construction to echo the `dataclasses` example. I could have omitted the default value `=0`, in which case `quantity_on_hand: int` would be just a type annotation, as for the other two variables"?

Comment: @Bananach: the `@dataclass` generates roughly the same `__init__` method, with a `quantity_on_hand` keyword argument with default value. When you create an instance, it'll set the `quantity_on_hand` instance attribute, always. So my *first*, non-dataclass example uses the same pattern to echo what the dataclass generated code will do.

Comment: @Bananach: so in the first example, we *could* just omit setting an instance attribute and not shadow the class attribute, it is redundant setting it anyway in that sense, but dataclasses *do* set it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you please add information on how to use dataclass methods before setting the value of an dataclass attribute eg. filtering what I want to store in the attribute? Usually I would have done this in the `__init__()` method to call a class method on the input paramter and the store it in the attribute. Do I have to use the `post_init_()` method now?

Comment: @user2853437 your use case isn’t really supported by dataclasses; perhaps you would be better off using dataclasses’ bigger cousin, [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/). That project supports per-field [converters](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#converters) that let you normalise field values. If you want to stick with dataclasses, then yes, do normalisation in the `__post_init__` method.

Comment: It should be noted somewhere that the reduced example is copied directly from the Python documentation.  I don't see that attributed anywhere in the answer.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: @swimfar2: My answer [predates the documentation commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/98d50cb8f57eb227c373cb94b8680b12ec8aade5) by 5 months. I based it it on the original PEP but had tweaked it for answer clarity. I’ve added a line to that effect.

Comment: Advent of code? Talk about appropriation.

Answer (score 255):

## Overview

The question has been addressed.  However, this answer adds some practical examples to aid in the basic understanding of dataclasses.

> What exactly are python data classes and when is it best to use them?

1. *code generators*: generate boilerplate code; you can choose to implement special methods in a regular class or have a dataclass implement them automatically.
2. *data containers*: structures that hold data (e.g. tuples and dicts), often with dotted, attribute access such as [classes, `namedtuple` and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357581/using-python-class-as-a-data-container).

> "mutable namedtuples with default[s]"

Here is what the latter phrase means:

- *mutable*: by default, dataclass attributes can be reassigned.  You can optionally make them immutable (see Examples below).
- *namedtuple*: you have dotted, attribute access like a `namedtuple` or a regular class.
- *default*: you can assign default values to attributes.

Compared to common classes, you primarily save on typing boilerplate code.

---

## Features

This is an overview of dataclass features (TL;DR? See the Summary Table in the next section).

### What you get

Here are features you get by default from dataclasses.

*Attributes + Representation + Comparison*

```
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
#@dataclasses.dataclass()                                       # alternative
class Color:
    r : int = 0
    g : int = 0
    b : int = 0
```

These defaults are provided by automatically setting the following keywords to `True`:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(init=True, repr=True, eq=True)
```

### What you can turn on

Additional features are available if the appropriate keywords are set to `True`.

*Order*

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(order=True)
class Color:
    r : int = 0
    g : int = 0
    b : int = 0
```

The ordering methods are now implemented (overloading operators: `< > <= >=`), similarly to [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) with stronger equality tests.

*Hashable, Mutable*

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)                        # override base `__hash__`
class Color:
    ...
```

Although the object is potentially mutable (possibly undesired), a hash is implemented.

*Hashable, Immutable*

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)                             # `eq=True` (default) to be immutable 
class Color:
    ...
```

A hash is now implemented and changing the object or assigning to attributes is disallowed.

Overall, the object is hashable if either `unsafe_hash=True` or `frozen=True`.

See also the original [hashing logic table](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/blob/d4c87c663feb0617fd8c7e6fe0a58882c4ccd468/dataclasses.py#L115) with more details.

*Optimization*

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(slots=True)              # py310+
class SlottedColor:
    #__slots__ = ["r", "b", "g"]                # alternative
    r : int
    g : int
    b : int
```

The object size is now reduced:

```
>>> imp sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(Color)
1056
>>> sys.getsizeof(SlottedColor)
888
```

`slots=True` was added in Python 3.10.  (Thanks @ajskateboarder).

In some circumstances, `slots=True`/`__slots__` also improves the speed of creating instances and accessing attributes.  Also, slots do not allow default assignments; otherwise, a `ValueError` is raised. If `__slot__` already exists, `slots=True` will cause a `TypeError`.

See more on slots in this [blog post](https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/#optimizing-data-classes).

See more on [arguments added in Python 3.10+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses): `match_args`, `kw_only`, `slots`, `weakref_slot`.

### What you don't get

To get the following features, special methods must be manually implemented:

*Unpacking*

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Color:
    r : int = 0
    g : int = 0
    b : int = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from dataclasses.astuple(self)
```

---

## Summary Table

```
+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|       Feature        |       Keyword        |                      Example                       |           Implement in a Class          |
+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Attributes           |  init                |  Color().r -> 0                                    |  __init__                               |
| Representation       |  repr                |  Color() -> Color(r=0, g=0, b=0)                   |  __repr__                               |
| Comparision*         |  eq                  |  Color() == Color(0, 0, 0) -> True                 |  __eq__                                 |
|                      |                      |                                                    |                                         |
| Order                |  order               |  sorted([Color(0, 50, 0), Color()]) -> ...         |  __lt__, __le__, __gt__, __ge__         |
| Hashable             |  unsafe_hash/frozen  |  {Color(), {Color()}} -> {Color(r=0, g=0, b=0)}    |  __hash__                               |
| Immutable            |  frozen + eq         |  Color().r = 10 -> TypeError                       |  __setattr__, __delattr__               |
| Optimization         |  slots               |  sys.getsizeof(SlottedColor) -> 888                |  __slots__                              |
|                      |                      |                                                    |                                         |
| Unpacking+           |  -                   |  r, g, b = Color()                                 |  __iter__                               |
+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

<sub><sup>*</sup> `__ne__` is not needed and thus [not implemented](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/blob/d4c87c663feb0617fd8c7e6fe0a58882c4ccd468/dataclasses.py#L882).</sub>

<sub><sup>+</sup>These methods are not automatically generated and require manual implementation in a dataclass.</sub>

---

## Additional features

*Post-initialization*

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class RGBA:
    r : int = 0
    g : int = 0
    b : int = 0
    a : float = 1.0

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.a : int =  int(self.a * 255)


RGBA(127, 0, 255, 0.5)
# RGBA(r=127, g=0, b=255, a=127)
```

*Inheritance*

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class RGBA(Color):
    a : int = 0
```

*Conversions*

Convert a dataclass to a tuple or a dict, [recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564841/creating-nested-dataclass-objects-in-python):

```
>>> dataclasses.astuple(Color(128, 0, 255))
(128, 0, 255)
>>> dataclasses.asdict(Color(128, 0, 255))
{'r': 128, 'g': 0, 'b': 255}
```

Limitations

- Lacks mechanisms to handle [starred arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764873/is-it-possible-to-use-args-in-a-dataclass)
- Working with [nested dataclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564841/creating-nested-dataclass-objects-in-python) can be complicated

---

## References

- R. Hettinger's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw) on *Dataclasses: The code generator to end all code generators*
- T. Hunner's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COMRNKAVesI) on *Easier Classes: Python Classes Without All the Cruft*
- Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-level-decorators-classes-and-functions) on hashing details
- Real Python's [guide](https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/) on *The Ultimate Guide to Data Classes in Python 3.7*
- A. Shaw's [blog post](https://hackernoon.com/a-brief-tour-of-python-3-7-data-classes-22ee5e046517) on *A brief tour of Python 3.7 data classes*
- E. Smith's [github repository](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses) on *dataclasses*

Comment: I would give two likes if it were possible. Very nice answer @pylang. I tip my hat to you Sir/Madam ;)

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one. Bravo!

Comment: I do love these micro-blog length extended responses. Well formatted, sectioned into digestable headings, code snippets and a references sections.

Comment: any idea why duck typing / type inference e.g. `@dataclasses.dataclass class RGB(r=255,g=0,b=0)` were not supported? For the basic struct type that shorthand is important to me

Comment: Would it make sense to use a `@dataclass` while turning all features off? And with what exactly would you end up with?

Comment: Note that as of Python 3.10, slots can be created automatically with `@dataclass(slots=True)`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-contents

Answer (score 8):

From the [PEP specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/):

> A class decorator is provided which inspects a class definition for
> variables with type annotations as defined in PEP 526, "Syntax for
> Variable Annotations". In this document, such variables are called
> fields. Using these fields, the decorator adds generated method
> definitions to the class to support instance initialization, a repr,
> comparison methods, and optionally other methods as described in the
> Specification section. Such a class is called a Data Class, but
> there's really nothing special about the class: the decorator adds
> generated methods to the class and returns the same class it was
> given.

The `@dataclass` generator adds methods to the class that you'd otherwise have to define yourself like `__repr__`, `__init__`, `__lt__`, and `__gt__`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider this simple class `Foo`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Foo:    
    def bar():
        pass
```

Here is the `dir()` built-in comparison. On the left-hand side is the `Foo` without the @dataclass decorator, and on the right is with the @dataclass decorator.

[image]

Here is another diff, after using the `inspect` module for comparison.

[image]