# In python 3.6, a loose statement that looks like "key: value", but outside of a dictionary context, is valid syntax. What is this syntax used for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm guessing this is documented somewhere and has been discussed before, and I will close this question if someone finds a duplicate.

In python 3.6 I can enter the line

```
foo: "bar"
```

or

```
x: 1.2345
```

and this appears to be valid syntax. That is, any set of characters formatted like a **variable name** followed by a colon then some **object** does not raise an error. I've been using python for quite a while so this was really surprising to me. What is the interpreter seeing here? What is this for?

I came across this when reading about `python3.7` and the new `@dataclass` decorator; I noticed the examples use the syntax

```
@dataclass
class Color:
    lightness: float = 0.5
    hue: float
    saturation: float
```

and assumed this loose `key: value` syntax was new. Evidently not.

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea what the jargon was so didn't know what to search for.

Comment: And here's the dupe for @dataclass https://stackoverflow.com/q/47955263/6622817