# Is it possible to use *args in a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I recently started using [dataclasses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) and they will be a nice addition to 3.7.  I'm curious if or how it is possible to recreate the same functionality of this class using dataclasses.

```
class Nav(object):
    def __init__(self, name:str, menu, page, *submenus):
        self.name = name
        self.menu = menu
        self.page = page
        self.submenus = submenus

foo = Nav("name", "menu", "page")
```

This doesn't work. Raises Exception `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'submenus'`

```
@dataclass
class Nav(object):
    name:str
    menu: Any
    page: Any
    submenus: tuple

foo = Nav("name", "menu", "page")
```

I assume this is because the class doesn't have the instructions to do the unpacking of the arguments.  **Is there some way to instruct the dataclass decorator that submenus needs to be unpacked?**

Comment: Python3.7 is not stable now. Maybe this is just a bug?

Comment: Unpopular opinion: That's not how varargs should be used. Just use a list.

Comment: @JaredSmith I added a better example of how it doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, when typing tuples unless you know the concrete type and length or are making immutability part of the API contract, I'd use `Iterable` instead. I'd use that instead of `List` too.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I had a similar thought; just pass in an actual tuple.

Comment: [untested idea]try manually unpacking in post-init[/untested idea]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see in the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#custom-init-method) an example of how to override the `__init__`.

> Sometimes the generated **init** method does not suffice. For example,
>   suppose you wanted to have an object to store *args and **kwargs:
>
> ```
> @dataclass(init=False)
> class ArgHolder:
>     args: List[Any]
>     kwargs: Mapping[Any, Any]
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.args = args
>         self.kwargs = kwargs
>
> a = ArgHolder(1, 2, three=3)
> ```

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  The decorator gives you a nice `__repr__`, but yeah I'm a little disappointed.

Comment: A year later and I have to take back my comment. Raymond Hettinger gave a talk at PyCon 2018 going over why the dataclass is still pretty great (even if we have to override the __init__) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw

Comment: It seems like, if you use this, then you can't use `frozen=True`. Such a shame!