# Python mypy unable to infer type from union return types

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

Here is the sample code

```
from typing import Dict, Union, Tuple


def select_range(data: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    if data['start'] and data['end']:
        return data['start'], data['end']
    return 1, 1

select_range({})
```

Mypy output:

```
mypy different_return.py
different_return.py:6: error: Incompatible return value type (got 
"Tuple[Union[str, int], Union[str, int]]", expected "Tuple[int, int]")
```

Even though one of the dictionary values is `int`, mypy is unable to infer that.

Comment: `mypy` is correct. You have the dict values as `Union[str, int]` but the return type in the signature as `int`. Change the return type or don't specify the type of the values in `data`.

Comment: Your function accepts a dictionary where the values can be either strings or integers, and it returns two such values. **You can't then claim you always return integers then**.

Comment: I think the misconception you have here is that these types are *static*, but you are thinking of the actual concrete values you're returning at runtime. That's not how static type systems work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Even though one of the dictionary values is int, mypy is unable to infer that.

Mypy is correct. Your code has a bug and mypy is correctly flagging it. There is no guarantee in your code that `data['start']` and `data['end']` are always going to be integers.

Your `data` signature is `Dict[str, Union[str, int]]`, so the values have the type `Union[str, int]`. Mypy *must* assume that it is always correct to pass in `{'start': '2018-07-12', 'end': -42}`, so the return value *must* be `Tuple[Union[str, int], Union[str, int]]`. Your claim that the function returns `Tuple[int, int]` clashes with this.

It doesn't matter what *actually* happens at runtime. That's not the point; mypy is a static typechecker, and is designed to help keep your runtime behaviour bug-free. What matters here is that, according to the type hints, it is *possible* to pass in non-integer values for `start` and `end`, so the typechecker can't protect you from future bugs in your code that accidentally set a string value for either of those two keys.

If you are passing around structured data in dictionaries, you will always have to fight mypy over this, as dictionaries are really the wrong structure for this. You really want to use a named tuple or [a dataclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes) here.

I'm using the name `FooBar` here, but for your specific application I'm sure there will be a better name for the data structure you are passing around:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class FooBar(NamedTuple):
    start: int
    end: int
    # other fields, perhaps with defaults and Optionals


def select_range(data: FooBar) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    if data.start and data.end:
        return data.start, data.end
    return 1, 1
```

Answer (score -1):

everything is good with code. you forget get you function params:

```
from typing import Dict, Union, Tuple


def select_range(data: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    print (data)
    if data['start'] and data['end']:
        return data['start'], data['end']
    return 1, 1

print (select_range({"start":[1,5], 'end':[2,6]}))
```

use this for looking some params:

`from typing import Dict, Union, Tuple`

```
def select_range(data: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]) -> Tuple[int, int]:
#    print (data)
    if 'start' in data and 'end' in data:
        return data['start'], data['end']
    return 1, 1

print (select_range({"start":[5], 'end':[6]}))
#select_range({})
```

([5], [6]) is a result of work

Comment: No, even adding the value also throws up with the same error.

Comment: No, the same error will still be raised, because mypy is a static type checker. It doesn't matter what actually happens during runtime. Besides, you are now passing in **lists** as the values. `Union[str, int]` does not mean that the values are lists of integers, the values must by either integers or strings.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what this question is about. Do you understand how type hinting works, what the `Dict[...]` and `Union[...]` and `Tuple[...]` syntax signifies?

Comment: i think the problem is in that you assert in code that you have in dict keys like "start" and "end" but when you don't have them, you have a error... you need check have your dict a key or not. you can do this: if "some_need_key" in name_of_dict

Comment: Your example code fails to pass mypy checks. The function implementation and calls were not at fault, the *type hint declarations were*. It didn't matter that the keys were missing (that was not the issue in the question). (Your code *still* produces `Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[Union[str, int], Union[str, int]]", expected "Tuple[int, int]")`, *and* it adds `Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "str": "List[int]"; expected "str": "Union[str, int]"` and `Dict entry 1 has incompatible type "str": "List[int]"; expected "str": "Union[str, int]"`, because you are using lists).