# Creating nested dataclass objects in Python

Tags: python, object, serialization, nested, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass object that has nested dataclass objects in it. However, when I create the main object, the nested objects turn into a dictionary:

```
@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: int
    f_two: str
    
@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: One


Two(**{'f_three': 'three', 'f_four': {'f_one': 1, 'f_two': 'two'}})

Two(f_three='three', f_four={'f_one': 1, 'f_two': 'two'})

obj = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four': One(**{'f_one': 1, 'f_two': 'two'})}

Two(**obj)
Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=1, f_two='two'))
```

As you can see only `**obj` works.

Ideally I'd like to construct my object to get something like this:

```
Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=1, f_two='two'))
```

Is there any way to achieve that other than manually converting nested dictionaries to corresponding dataclass object, whenever accessing object attributes?

Comment: Your second approach wordks fine if you actually use `obj`.  `Two(**obj)` gives me `Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=1, f_two='two'))`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Any idea if it's possible to do achieve the same result using the first approach? Second approach seems too tedious, if you have multiple nested objects in your dataclass object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dataclass from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376099/python-dataclass-from-dict)

Comment: this seems to work today (python 3.7 and 3.9):
`a=Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=1, f_two='two')); print(a)`

Comment: You can look into chili library, which simplifies a lot of serialization and deserialization of data classes. It has couple of nice additional features like mapping and field hiding: https://github.com/kodemore/chili

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a request that is as complex as the `dataclasses` module itself, which means that probably the best way to achieve this "nested fields" capability is to define a new decorator, akin to `@dataclass`.

Fortunately, if you don't need the signature of the `__init__` method to reflect the fields and their defaults, like the classes rendered by calling `dataclass`, this can be a whole lot simpler:  A class decorator that will call the original `dataclass`  and wrap some functionality over its generated `__init__` method can do it with a plain "`...(*args, **kwargs):`" style function.

In other words, all one needs to do is write a wrapper around the generated `__init__` method that will inspect the parameters passed in "kwargs", check if any corresponds to a "dataclass field type", and if so, generate the nested object prior to calling the original `__init__`. Maybe this is harder to spell out in English than in Python:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, is_dataclass

def nested_dataclass(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(cls):
        cls = dataclass(cls, **kwargs)
        original_init = cls.__init__
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for name, value in kwargs.items():
                field_type = cls.__annotations__.get(name, None)
                if is_dataclass(field_type) and isinstance(value, dict):
                     new_obj = field_type(**value)
                     kwargs[name] = new_obj
            original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
        cls.__init__ = __init__
        return cls
    return wrapper(args[0]) if args else wrapper
```

Note that besides not worrying about `__init__` signature, this
also ignores passing `init=False` - since it would be meaningless anyway.

(The `if` in the return line is responsible for this to work either being called with named parameters or directly as a decorator, like `dataclass` itself)

And on the interactive prompt:

```
In [85]: @dataclass
    ...: class A:
    ...:     b: int = 0
    ...:     c: str = ""
    ...:         

In [86]: @dataclass
    ...: class A:
    ...:     one: int = 0
    ...:     two: str = ""
    ...:     
    ...:         

In [87]: @nested_dataclass
    ...: class B:
    ...:     three: A
    ...:     four: str
    ...:     

In [88]: @nested_dataclass
    ...: class C:
    ...:     five: B
    ...:     six: str
    ...:     
    ...:     

In [89]: obj = C(five={"three":{"one": 23, "two":"narf"}, "four": "zort"}, six="fnord")

In [90]: obj.five.three.two
Out[90]: 'narf'
```

If you want the signature to be kept, I'd recommend using the private helper functions in the `dataclasses` module itself, to create a new `__init__`.

Comment: You have chained attrs with a decorator.  That's awesome.

Comment: Indeed - I think this snippet may deserve a Pypi module on its own. I see that it is published.

Comment: For the record, `dataclasses.is_dataclass(f.type)` return false for fields of type `List[dataclass]`, so your decorator skips over such fields. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376099/python-dataclasse-from-dict?noredirect=1#comment93683831_53376099

Comment: Note that this address works, however, dataclasses use deepcopy() internally which can slow down things significantly when it comes to data sterilization of large objects.

Comment: *update*: people needing this, please check the "pydantic" library - I think it can handle this, with enough code to provide for the corner cases.

Comment: I like to add a `elif field_type is None` clause so that I can `warn()` about ignored extra fields. Then `else: new_kwargs[name] = value` to finish it off.

Comment: pointing to @mbatchkarov comment. I am looking for exactly that. Anyone?

Comment: It is an "elif" condition and 2 more lines on the code above. One should be able to that on their own. (I won't be updatinbg the answer now, but I might rewrite this code as a gist so it works with lists)

Answer (score 47):

You can use post_init for this

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: int
    f_two: str

@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: One
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.f_four = One(**self.f_four)

data = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four': {'f_one': 1, 'f_two': 'two'}}

print(Two(**data))
# Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=1, f_two='two'))
```

Comment: Nice answer but f_four expect a dict and not a instance of One.
We can use the Union type like so [One, dict]

Comment: this was the answer I was looking for. Would prefer not to use an external library if possible for something pretty trivial.

Comment: What about default values for `class Two`? It don't allow to define `f_four: One = One(11, '22')`

Answer (score 22):

You can try [`dacite`](https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite/) module. This package simplifies creation of data classes from dictionaries - it also supports nested structures.

Example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict

@dataclass
class A:
    x: str
    y: int

@dataclass
class B:
    a: A

data = {
    'a': {
        'x': 'test',
        'y': 1,
    }
}

result = from_dict(data_class=B, data=data)

assert result == B(a=A(x='test', y=1))
```

To install dacite, simply use pip:

```
$ pip install dacite
```

Answer (score 13):

Instead of writing a new decorator I came up with a function modifying all fields of type `dataclass` after the actual `dataclass` is initialized.

```py
def dicts_to_dataclasses(instance):
    """Convert all fields of type `dataclass` into an instance of the
    specified data class if the current value is of type dict."""
    cls = type(instance)
    for f in dataclasses.fields(cls):
        if not dataclasses.is_dataclass(f.type):
            continue

        value = getattr(instance, f.name)
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            continue

        new_value = f.type(**value)
        setattr(instance, f.name, new_value)
```

The function could be called manually or in `__post_init__`. This way the `@dataclass` decorator can be used in all its glory.

The example from above with a call to `__post_init__`:

```py
@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: int
    f_two: str

@dataclass
class Two:
    def __post_init__(self):
        dicts_to_dataclasses(self)

    f_three: str
    f_four: One

data = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four': {'f_one': 1, 'f_two': 'two'}}

two = Two(**data)
# Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=1, f_two='two'))
```

Answer (score 6):

I have created an augmentation of the solution by @jsbueno that also accepts typing in the form `List[<your class/>]`.

```
def nested_dataclass(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(cls):
        cls = dataclass(cls, **kwargs)
        original_init = cls.__init__

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for name, value in kwargs.items():
                field_type = cls.__annotations__.get(name, None)
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    if field_type.__origin__ == list or field_type.__origin__ == List:
                        sub_type = field_type.__args__[0]
                        if is_dataclass(sub_type):
                            items = []
                            for child in value:
                                if isinstance(child, dict):
                                    items.append(sub_type(**child))
                            kwargs[name] = items
                if is_dataclass(field_type) and isinstance(value, dict):
                    new_obj = field_type(**value)
                    kwargs[name] = new_obj
            original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

        cls.__init__ = __init__
        return cls

    return wrapper(args[0]) if args else wrapper
```

Comment: Using your decorator I get: AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute '__origin__' if one of dataclasses attribute is annotated List[SomeClass]

Answer (score 2):

Very important question is not nesting, but value validation / casting. Do you need validation of values?

If value validation is needed, stay with well-tested deserialization libs like:

- `pydantic` (faster but messy reserved attributes like `schema` interfere with attribute names coming from data. Have to rename and alias class properties enough to make it annoying)
- `schematics` (slower than pydantic, but much more mature typecasting stack)

They have amazing validation and re-casting support and are used very widely (meaning, should generally work well and not mess up your data). However, they are not `dataclass` based, though Pydantic wraps `dataclass` functionality and allows you to switch from pure dataclasses to Pydantic-supported dataclasses with change of import statement.

These libs (mentioned in this thread) work with dataclasses natively, but validation / typecasting is not hardened yet.

- `dacite`
- `validated_dc`

If validation is not super important, and just recursive nesting is needed, simple hand-rolled code like https://gist.github.com/dvdotsenko/07deeafb27847851631bfe4b4ddd9059 is enough to deal with `Optional` and `List[` `Dict[` nested models.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with pairing this functionality with the non-stdlib library attrs (a superset of the functionality that dataclass stdlib provides), then [the `cattrs` library](https://github.com/Tinche/cattrs) provides a `structure` function which handles the conversion of native data types to dataclasses and will use type annotations automatically.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use chili. This is a library which I build precisely for this purpose. The only change you would need to do in your code is just import one function like the below:

```py
from chili import init_dataclass

@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: int
    f_two: str
    
@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: One


two = init_dataclass({'f_three': 'three', 'f_four': {'f_one': 1, 'f_two': 'two'}}, Two)
```

Installatoin is simple:

`pip install chili`

or

`poetry add chili`

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/kodemore/chili

Answer (score 1):

[**dataclass-wizard**](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) is a modern option that can alternatively work for you. It supports complex types such as date and time, generics from the `typing` module, and a *nested dataclass* structure.

Other "nice to have" features such as implicit key casing transforms - i.e. *camelCase* and *TitleCase*, which are quite common in API responses - are likewise supported out of box.

The "new style" annotations introduced in PEPs [585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) and [604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/) can be ported back to Python 3.7 via a `__future__` import as shown below.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import fromdict, asdict, DumpMeta


@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str | None
    f_four: list[One]


@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: int
    f_two: str


data = {'f_three': 'three',
        'f_four': [{'f_one': 1, 'f_two': 'two'},
                   {'f_one': '2', 'f_two': 'something else'}]}

two = fromdict(Two, data)
print(two)

# setup key transform for serialization (default is camelCase)
DumpMeta(key_transform='SNAKE').bind_to(Two)

my_dict = asdict(two)
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
Two(f_three='three', f_four=[One(f_one=1, f_two='two'), One(f_one=2, f_two='something else')])
{'f_three': 'three', 'f_four': [{'f_one': 1, 'f_two': 'two'}, {'f_one': 2, 'f_two': 'something else'}]}
```

---

You can install Dataclass Wizard via `pip`:

```
$ pip install dataclass-wizard
```

Comment: I have built a library which does a very similar thing with one exception that, from my perspective, is a deal breaker. You don't have to extend anything in order for it to work. It covers almost everything which you can find in the typing package: https://github.com/kodemore/chili

Answer (score 1):

Your example works as desired for recent Python versions.

However, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) is still completely lacking for nesting `dataclasses`. If there are default parameters, the following methods also work:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: int = 1
    f_two: str = 'two'
    
@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str = 'three'
    f_four: One = One()

# nested class instance with default parameters
example = Two()
example

# nested class instance with different parameters
example = Two(f_three='four', f_four=One(f_one=2, f_two='three'))
example

# same but using dict unpacking
example = Two(**{'f_three': 'five', 'f_four': One(**{'f_one': 3, 'f_two': 'four'})})
example

# or, by changing the class initialization method to ingest a vanilla dict:
@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str = '3'
    f_four: One = One()
    def __init__(self, d: dict):
        self.f_three = d.get('f_three')
        self.f_four  = One(**d.get('f_four'))

d = {'f_three': 'six', 'f_four': {'f_one': 4, 'f_two': 'five'}}
example = Two(d)
example
```

The important thing here is that the class member pointing to the nested `dataclass` should have the type of the `dataclass` and be initialized with its values. You can nest together as many levels of `dataclasses` as you like this way.

Another way is to simply use a `dict`, which is easily serialized/deserialized to/from JSON:

```py
# dict is all you need
example = {
    'three': '3',
    'four': {
        'one': 1,
        'two': '2',
    }
}
```

An old hack borrowed from [Kaggle](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-environments/blob/master/kaggle_environments/utils.py) is to unpack a nested `list` or `dict` into a `Struct`, which is not a `dataclass`, for dot access:

```py
class Struct(dict):
    """Dataclass structure that inherits from dict."""
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        entries = {k: v for k, v in entries.items() if k != 'items'}
        dict.__init__(self, entries)
        self.__dict__.update(entries)
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self.__dict__[attr] = value
        self[attr] = value

def structify(obj: Union[list,dict]) -> Struct:
    """Unpack list or dict into Struct for dot access of members."""
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [structify(obj[i]) for i in range(len(obj))]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return Struct(**{k: structify(v) for k, v in obj.items()})
    return obj  # else return input object

s = structify(example)
s
s.three
s.four.one
s.four.two
```

You could also create a [TypedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict), but why combine the worst aspects of dictionaries and classes? There should be no need for an external library for such a basic thing provided by every other language. You would expect nested dataclasses to behave like nested C/C++ structs, but it is very different. Otherwise, [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/) has a nice interface for typed classes generated from unpacked dictionaries. Overall, Julia has better methods for dealing with parameter data structures in the `@kwdef` macro:

```
@kwdef struct Foo
    a::Int = 1     # default value
    b::String      # required keyword
end

Foo(b="hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class Foo(ValidatedDC):
    one: int
    two: str


@dataclass
class Bar(ValidatedDC):
    three: str
    foo: Foo


data = {'three': 'three', 'foo': {'one': 1, 'two': 'two'}}
bar = Bar(**data)
assert bar == Bar(three='three', foo=Foo(one=1, two='two'))

data = {'three': 'three', 'foo': Foo(**{'one': 1, 'two': 'two'})}
bar = Bar(**data)
assert bar == Bar(three='three', foo=Foo(one=1, two='two'))

# Use asdict() to work with the dictionary:

bar_dict = asdict(bar)
assert bar_dict == {'three': 'three', 'foo': {'one': 1, 'two': 'two'}}

foo_dict = asdict(bar.foo)
assert foo_dict == {'one': 1, 'two': 'two'}
```

ValidatedDC: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

Answer (score 0):

you can try `datclass` library:

```bash
$ pip install datclass

$ datclass -r
Please paste the JSON string - Ctrl-D Return
{"f_three": "three", "f_four": {"f_one": 1, "f_two": "two"}}
<CTRL-D>
from datclass import dataclass, List, DatClass


@dataclass
class FFour(DatClass):
    f_one: int = None
    f_two: str = None


@dataclass
class Object(DatClass):
    f_three: str = None
    f_four: FFour = None

 Generate successful
```

```py
from datclass import dataclass, DatClass


@dataclass
class FFour(DatClass):
    f_one: int = None
    f_two: str = None


@dataclass
class Object(DatClass):
    f_three: str = None
    f_four: FFour = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Object(**{"f_three": "three", "f_four": {"f_one": 1, "f_two": "two"}})
    print(obj)

>>> Object(f_three='three', f_four=FFour(f_one=1, f_two='two'))
```