# accessing type of typing.List

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I'm currently writing code and need to know if a given type annotation is an iterable (e.g. `ta = typing.List[str]`)

I was expecting s.th. like this to work:

```
if isinstance(ta, typing.List):
    # do s.th.
```

However, ta is of type `typing._GenericAlias` which has not much to do with typing.List.

Instead I have to use the '**origin**' attribute like this:

```
if getattr(ta, '__origin__', None) == list:
    # do s.th.
```

Is this really the correct way to do it?

Comment: Well, consider that `isinstance(list, Iterable)` *similarly* wouldn't work...

Comment: The three iterable instances I know are `list,str,and dict` is there any other?? just do `if isinstance(ta, (list,str,dict)):`

Comment: but ta is not the actual iterable, it's the type-hint `typing.List`. To rephrase:

I'm confused because `isinstance(List[str], List)` returns false...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly are you trying to do? Type hints are meant to basically be invisible at runtime -- introspecting the type hints themselves at runtime isn't a very well-supported or common use case.

Comment: I'm using the python3.7 dataclass and like to init it from a dict - with nested structures.

    @dataclass
    class Foo
        x: typing.List(Bar)

As I have many of those nested structure (which I init from a dict) I would prefer not to write separate `__post_init__` routines for every nested attribute but write a new decorator (e.g. `nested_dataclass`) which does the attribute dataclass creation on the fly (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564841/creating-nested-dataclass-objects-in-python - which exactly leaves this point out)

Answer (score 0):

In CPython 3.8:

```
from typing import_GenericAlias

# Now, let's suppose that you have a class "cls"
name = "your_attribute"
typ = cls.__annotations__[name]
if isinstance(typ, _GenericAlias) and typ._name == "List":
    print("This is a list type")
```

`_GenericAlias` is a protected/generated class that is undocumented. It is an implementation detail. I don't know any reliable way of accessing type information at runtime.

Comment: This was not the question, but you might find https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ better suited for your needs. It has 4500+ stars on GitHub. There are other similar libs out there that provide runtime type information. (But then you might loose type checking in your IDE.)