# Decorator to Nested List of Dataclass in Python

Tags: python, list, nested, decorator, python-dataclasses

I'd like to create a dict to a dataclass which contains as a List of dataclass as attribute

Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class level2:
    key21: int
    key22: int


@nested_dataclass
class level1:
    key1: int
    key2: List[level2]


data = {
    'key1': value1,
    'key2': [{
        'key21': value21,
        'key22': value22,
    }]
}

my_object = level1(**data)
print(my_object.key2[0].key21) #should print value21
```

Closest decorator I found was this one, but it does not work with Lists of dataclass:
[Creating nested dataclass objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564841/creating-nested-dataclass-objects-in-python)

```
def is_dataclass(obj):
    """Returns True if obj is a dataclass or an instance of a
    dataclass."""
    _FIELDS = '__dataclass_fields__'
    return hasattr(obj, _FIELDS)


def nested_dataclass(*args, **kwargs):

    def wrapper(cls):
        cls = dataclass(cls, **kwargs)
        original_init = cls.__init__

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for name, value in kwargs.items():
                field_type = cls.__annotations__.get(name, None)

                if is_dataclass(field_type) and isinstance(value, dict):
                     new_obj = field_type(**value)
                     kwargs[name] = new_obj

            original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

        cls.__init__ = __init__
        return cls

    return wrapper(args[0]) if args else wrapper
```

How would you modify this decorator or create one that would do the job?
(I've got zero experience in building decorator)

Any comment/code is very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: key2 should be a list right? I don't think your declaration of `data` is correct

Comment: Right, modifying the post, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I changed the decorator a bit but it is very specific to the example provided here. The main issue was that your `List[level2]` field was not a `dataclass`. So to go around that I played around a bit and noticed that there was an **args** property that could tell you the nested type in the list. I've never work with dataclasses before (except with pydantic) so perhaps there is a better answer out there

```py
def nested_dataclass(*args, **kwargs):

    def wrapper(cls):
        cls = dataclass(cls, **kwargs)
        original_init = cls.__init__

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for name, value in kwargs.items():
                field_type = cls.__annotations__.get(name, None)

                if hasattr(field_type, '__args__'):
                    inner_type = field_type.__args__[0]
                    if is_dataclass(inner_type):
                        new_obj = [inner_type(**dict_) for dict_ in value]
                        kwargs[name] = new_obj

            original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

        cls.__init__ = __init__
        return cls

    return wrapper(args[0]) if args else wrapper


@dataclass
class level2:
    key21: int
    key22: int

@nested_dataclass
class level1:
    key1: int
    key2: List[level2]


data = {
    'key1': 1,
    'key2': [{
        'key21': 21,
        'key22': 22,
    },
    {
     'key21': 23,
     'key22': 24
     }]
}

my_object = level1(**data)
print(my_object.key2[0].key21) #should print 21
print(my_object.key2[1].key21) #should print 23

@nested_dataclass
class random:
    key1: int
    key2: List[int]

random_object = random(**{'key1': 1, 'key2': [1,2,3]})
print(random_object.key2) # prints [1,2,3]
```

Further nesting

```
@nested_dataclass
class level3:
    key3: List[level1]

level3(**{'key3': [data]})
```

Output:

```
level3(key3=[level1(key1=1, key2=[level2(key21=21, key22=22), level2(key21=23, key22=24)])])
```

Comment: Just found a case where it does not work:

dataclass
class level3:
    key31: int

nested_dataclass
class level2:
    key21: level3

nested_dataclass
class level1:
    key11: List[level2]

data = {
    'key11': [{
        'key21': {
            'key31': 21,
        }
    }]
}

my_object = level1(**data)
print(my_object) 

However, if
nested_dataclass
class level2:
    key21: List[level3]

 it works. I don't really understand why. Any thoughts?

Comment: The solution I provided is very specific to the case as mentioned. Your new `level2` is not nested like the cases above where the nesting is only for a `List` of other data classes. You can modify the code I had to work for you want but to generalize it you will need far more code than that. So once again I suggest using `pydantic`

Comment: Thanks @Buckeye14Guy, will try to make it work and post the generalized solution

Answer (score 1):

pip install validated-dc

ValidatedDC: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Union

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class Level2(ValidatedDC):
    key21: int
    key22: int


@dataclass
class Level1(ValidatedDC):
    key1: int
    key2: List[Level2]


data = {
    'key1': 1,
    'key2': [{
        'key21': 21,
        'key22': 22,
    }]
}

my_object = Level1(**data)
assert my_object.key2[0].key21 == 21


# ----------------------------------

@dataclass
class Level1(ValidatedDC):
    key1: int
    key2: Union[Level2, List[Level2]]


my_object = Level1(**data)  # key2 - list
assert my_object.key2[0].key21 == 21

data['key2'] = {
    'key21': 21,
    'key22': 22,
}

my_object = Level1(**data)  # key2 - dict
assert my_object.key2.key21 == 21
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not provide how to change the decorator and **if you do not wish to use any 3rd party packages then please disregard this answer.** But I think that [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) can do what you want. The only reason I am suggesting is because it will not allow you to mistakenly have `key2` as a dictionary when it was declared to be a list.

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
class level2(BaseModel):
    key21: int
    key22: int

class level1(BaseModel):
    key1: int
    key2: List[level2]

data = {
    'key1': 1,
    'key2': [{
        'key21': 21,
        'key22': 22,
    }]
}

my_object = level1(**data)
print(my_object.key2[0].key21) # prints 21
```

If you actually wanted to have `key21` directly accessible from `key2` then

```py
class level1(BaseModel):
    key1: int
    key2: level2 # Not a list

data = {
    'key1': 1,
    'key2': {
        'key21': 21,
        'key22': 22,
    }
}

my_object = level1(**data)
print(my_object.key2.key21) # prints 21
```

Again ignore this if your goal is successfully get the decorator to work. Otherwise installing pydantic won't hurt :)

Comment: The main problem is that `List[level2]` is not a `data_class` so that `if` statement isn't being used.