# Python 3.8+ Nested data objects type validation with dacite

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, python-dataclasses

I have a question regrading nested data objects.

As suggested in other post ([Creating nested dataclass objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564841/creating-nested-dataclass-objects-in-python)), we can use dacite package to create nested data objects. This works on handling the data that we nested dictionary structure.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict

@dataclass
class A:
    x: str
    y: int

@dataclass
class B:
    a: A

data = {
    'a': {
        'x': 'test',
        'y': 1,
    }
}

result = from_dict(data_class=B, data=data)

assert result == B(a=A(x='test', y=1))
```

However I have a data type check function and type conversion function associate with the dataclass A in the example. Where I use `inspect.signature(A).parameters` to get the expected type of the dataclass and check if data are in the expected type. Can we also call the signature of class A from class B or is there any work around on this? Thanks.

The type current type check code is something like this:

```
expected_para = inspect.signature(A).parameters
def type_check(d_f: dict, expected_para):
    d_new = {}
    for k in expected_para.keys():
        # get expected type
        expected_type = expected_para[k].annotation
        # check if k in d_f
        if k in d_f.keys():
            # check type
            v = d_f[k]
           #type conversion here
            d_new[k] = self.typeconversion(expected_type, v)
        else:
            d_new[k] = None
    return d_new
```

Comment: look at post init https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing

Comment: hi @balderman I am not quite sure how post init would help in this case, would you mind elabrate more?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a validation function using `__post_init__()` like this:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    x: str
    y: int

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        assert self.y > 0, 'y must be greater than zero'
```