# How can I make a python dataclass hashable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass whose instances I want to hash and order, using the `id` member as a key.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(eq=True, order=True)
class Category:
    id: str = field(compare=True)
    name: str = field(default="set this in post_init", compare=False)
```

I know that I can implement `__hash__` myself. However, I would like dataclasses to do the work for me because they are intended to handle this.

---

Unfortunately, the above dataclass fails:

```
a = sorted(list(set([ Category(id='x'), Category(id='y')])))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Category'
```

Comment: To find examples, see the *What you can turn on* section in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283085/4531270.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass):

> Here are the rules governing implicit creation of a `__hash__()` method:
>
> [...]
>
> **If `eq` and `frozen` are both true, by default `dataclass()` will
> generate a `__hash__()` method for you.** If `eq` is true and `frozen`
> is false, `__hash__()` will be set to `None`, marking it unhashable
> (which it is, since it is mutable). If `eq` is false, `__hash__()`
> will be left untouched meaning the `__hash__()` method of the
> superclass will be used (if the superclass is object, this means it
> will fall back to id-based hashing).

Since you set `eq=True` and left `frozen` at the default (`False`), your dataclass is unhashable.

You have 3 options:

- Set `frozen=True` (in combination with the default `eq=True`), which will make your class immutable and hashable.

  ```
  @dataclass(frozen=True)
  ```
- Set `unsafe_hash=True`, which will create a `__hash__` method but leave your class mutable.

  ```
  @dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
  ```

  Mutability risks problems if an instance of your class is modified while stored in a dict or set:

  ```
  cat = Category('foo', 'bar')
  categories = {cat}
  cat.id = 'baz'

  print(cat in categories)  # False
  ```
- Manually implement a `__hash__` method.

Comment: As noted below, to exclude some field from being used for __hash__ generation in unsafe_hash, you can use field(compare=False) or field(hash=False)  (hash inherits compare value if not set.).

Comment: Note that manually implementing `__hash__()` is trivial in case of an ID-type field: `def __hash__(self): return hash(self.id)`

Answer (score 41):

**TL;DR**

Use `frozen=True` (which will make the instances immutable). `eq=True` is the default value and can be left out.

**Long Answer**

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-level-decorators-classes-and-functions):

> `__hash__()` is used by built-in `hash()`, and when objects are added to hashed collections such as dictionaries and sets. Having a `__hash__()`
> implies that instances of the class are immutable. Mutability is a
> complicated property that depends on the programmer’s intent, the
> existence and behavior of `__eq__()`, and the values of the eq and
> frozen flags in the `dataclass()` decorator.
>
> By default, `dataclass()` will not implicitly add a `__hash__()` method
> unless it is safe to do so. Neither will it add or change an existing
> explicitly defined `__hash__()` method. Setting the class attribute
> `__hash__ = None` has a specific meaning to Python, as described in the `__hash__()` documentation.
>
> If `__hash__()` is not explicit defined, or if it is set to None, then
> `dataclass()` may add an implicit `__hash__()` method. Although not
> recommended, you can force `dataclass()` to create a `__hash__()` method
> with `unsafe_hash=True`. This might be the case if your class is
> logically immutable but can nonetheless be mutated. This is a
> specialized use case and should be considered carefully.
>
> Here are the rules governing implicit creation of a `__hash__()` method.
> Note that you cannot both have an explicit `__hash__()` method in your
> dataclass and set `unsafe_hash=True`; this will result in a `TypeError`.
>
> If eq and frozen are both true, by default `dataclass()` will generate a
> `__hash__()` method for you. If eq is true and frozen is false, `__hash__()` will be set to None, marking it unhashable (which it is, since it is mutable). If eq is false, `__hash__()` will be left
> untouched meaning the `__hash__()` method of the superclass will be used
> (if the superclass is object, this means it will fall back to id-based
> hashing).

Answer (score 40):

I'd like to add a special note for use of unsafe_hash.

You can exclude fields from being compared by hash by setting compare=False, or hash=False.  (hash by default inherits from compare).

This might be useful if you store nodes in a graph but want to mark them visited without breaking their hashing (e.g if they're in a set of unvisited nodes..).

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class node:
    x:int
    visit_count: int = field(default=10, compare=False)  # hash inherits compare setting. So valid.
    # visit_count: int = field(default=False, hash=False)   # also valid. Arguably easier to read, but can break some compare code.
    # visit_count: int = False   # if mutated, hashing breaks. (3* printed)

s = set()
n = node(1)
s.add(n)
if n in s: print("1* n in s")
n.visit_count = 11
if n in s:
    print("2* n still in s")
else:
    print("3* n is lost to the void because hashing broke.")
```

This took me *hours* to figure out... Useful further readings I found is the python doc on dataclasses. Specifically see the field documentation and dataclass arg documentations.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: *This might be useful if you store nodes in a graph but want to mark them visited without breaking their hashing (e.g if they're in a set of unvisited nodes..).*: never have I felt more targeted by an example use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class Category:
```

*True* is the default for *eq*.