# Using hash for identity on Python dataclasses

Tags: python, identity

I have the following `Filer` entity (in the domain-driven design sense).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Address:
    street: str
    city: str
    state: str
    zipcode: str

@dataclass
class Filer:
    cik: int
    name: str = field(hash=False, compare=True)
    state: str = field(hash=False, compare=True)
    yearend: str = field(hash=False, compare=True)
    businessaddress: Address = field(hash=False, compare=True)
    mailingaddress: Address = field(hash=False, compare=True)
    sic: int = field(hash=False, compare=True)
    ein: str = field(hash=False, compare=True, default=None)
```

For any `Filer`, `cik` by itself determines identity. I would, however, like to use equality comparisons to see if any other details about the `Filer` may have changed (e.g. vs. a prior version of the same `Filer`). On that basis, I set `hash=False, compare=True` on all fields except `cik` (for which `hash=True`, by default).

The following testcase gives a quick overview of the intended behavior:

- Identity: fully determined by `cik` and tested via `AssertIs` and `AssertIsNot`
- Equality: determined by all fields and tested via `AssertEqual` and `AssertNotEqual`

```
import unittest

class TestFiler(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_equality_same_filer(self,):
        a = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        b = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        self.assertEqual(a, b)

    def test_identity_same_filer(self,):
        a = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        b = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        self.assertIs(a, b)

    def test_equality_same_filer_new_name(self,):
        a = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        b = Filer(1234, "A new name for the company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        self.assertNotEqual(a, b)

    def test_identity_same_filer_new_name(self,):
        a = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        b = Filer(1234, "A new name for the company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        self.assertIs(a, b)

    def test_equality_different_filer_same_details(self,):
        a = Filer(4321, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        b = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        self.assertNotEqual(a, b)

    def test_identity_different_filer_same_details(self,):
        a = Filer(4321, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        b = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                         1000,
                         1234567)
        self.assertIsNot(a, b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The results didn't go as intended.

```
base) randm@pearljam /home/randm/Projects/secfilings $ /home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/bin/python /home/randm/Projects/scrap/filer.py
....FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_identity_same_filer (__main__.TestFiler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/randm/Projects/scrap/filer.py", line 51, in test_identity_same_filer
    self.assertIs(a, b)
AssertionError: Filer(cik=1234, name='Some company', state='Some state', yearend='0930', businessaddress=Address(street='Some address', city='Some city', state='AB', zipcode='12345'), mailingaddress=Address(street='Some address', city='Some city', state='AB', zipcode='12345'), sic=1000, ein=1234567) is not Filer(cik=1234, name='Some company', state='Some state', yearend='0930', businessaddress=Address(street='Some address', city='Some city', state='AB', zipcode='12345'), mailingaddress=Address(street='Some address', city='Some city', state='AB', zipcode='12345'), sic=1000, ein=1234567)

======================================================================
FAIL: test_identity_same_filer_new_name (__main__.TestFiler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/randm/Projects/scrap/filer.py", line 77, in test_identity_same_filer_new_name
    self.assertIs(a, b)
AssertionError: Filer(cik=1234, name='Some company', state='Some state', yearend='0930', businessaddress=Address(street='Some address', city='Some city', state='AB', zipcode='12345'), mailingaddress=Address(street='Some address', city='Some city', state='AB', zipcode='12345'), sic=1000, ein=1234567) is not Filer(cik=1234, name='A new name for the company', state='Some state', yearend='0930', businessaddress=Address(street='Some address', city='Some city', state='AB', zipcode='12345'), mailingaddress=Address(street='Some address', city='Some city', state='AB', zipcode='12345'), sic=1000, ein=1234567)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Is there a way for me to use `is` identity tests (without resorting to a dataclass method `is_` or something like that, which would change the clean syntax I'm looking for in client code). Or am I simply misusing identity (which I believe is based on pointer values in CPython) and should instead be using hash equality explicitly in my client code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to override Python's `is` identity checks, as [@LhasaDad pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554331/1431750). It will always refer to objects being the actual same object. (Kinda works for strings but [behaves "unexpectedly" for integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/1431750).)

You could use [`unsafe_hash=True` (with `eq=True`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52390734/1431750) in the dataclass definitions so that you can use `hash(a) == hash(b)`. But then you may as well create a method `is_` and do `a.is_(b)` if you want it *feel* more natural. Be aware that if there are other users/coders of your classes, you need to be clear about when `is_` can be True but `==` can be false; and all other combos.

```
@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
Filer:
    ...  # everything else the same
```

Then your identity test for that would be based on `hash()`.

Also, you should be using test [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) for `a` and `b` instead of copy-pasting them in every test. Someone who reads your code (like us) still has to check the entire definition of both in each test, to see what's different. And in a month, so will you. For objects which are only slightly different for your tests, use [`dataclasses.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace).

Here's a more read-able version of the unit tests, with the hash-based checks added in:

```py
import dataclasses
import unittest

class TestFiler(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                       Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                       Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                       1000, 1234567)
        self.b = Filer(1234, "Some company", "Some state", "0930",
                       Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                       Address("Some address", "Some city", "AB", "12345"),
                       1000, 1234567)
    
    def test_equality_same_filer(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.a, self.b)
    
    def test_identity_same_filer(self):  # will still fail
        self.assertIs(self.a, self.b)
    
    def test_equality_same_filer_new_name(self):
        # make it clear that `a` and `c` only differ by name:
        c = dataclasses.replace(self.a, name="A new name for the company")
        self.assertNotEqual(self.a, c)
    
    def test_identity_same_filer_new_name(self):  # will still fail
        # or put c also in `setUp`
        c = dataclasses.replace(self.a, name="A new name for the company")
        self.assertIs(self.a, c)
    
    def test_equality_different_filer_same_details(self):
        new_a = dataclasses.replace(self.a, cik=4321)
        self.assertIsNot(new_a, self.a)  # better
    
    def test_identity_different_filer_same_details(self):
        new_a = dataclasses.replace(self.a, cik=4321)
        self.assertIsNot(new_a, self.a)
    
    def test_hash_same_filer(self):  # NEW
        self.assertEqual(hash(self.a), hash(self.b))
    
    def test_hash_same_filer_new_name(self):  # NEW
        c = dataclasses.replace(self.a, name="A new name for the company")
        self.assertEqual(hash(c), hash(self.a))
    
    def test_identity_different_filer_same_details(self):  # NEW
        diff_a = dataclasses.replace(self.a, cik=4321)
        self.assertNotEqual(hash(diff_a), hash(self.a))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are miss using **assertIs**.  it uses the **is** behavior of python.   that is,  they must be referring to the same object. since you have constructed 2 different objects the **is** test between them will always be false.  Equals is the correct test for equivalence.