# Get values from dictionary by class as a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

How can I make this work, I need to get values from dictionary by class as a key.

But I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'FirstClass'`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class FirstClass():
    name: str


@dataclass
class SecondClass():
    name: str


MAPPER = {FirstClass: 888, SecondClass: 999}

itr_list = [FirstClass(name="default_name"), SecondClass(name="default_name")]

for itr in itr_list:
    get_key = MAPPER[itr]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a python dataclass hashable without making them immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390576/how-can-i-make-a-python-dataclass-hashable-without-making-them-immutable)

Comment: Note that the suggested duplicate also has answers with a solution to do this for immutable dataclasses, which might also work for your case.

Comment: when access items in a dict you have to use the same key as you constructed it with. `FirstClass` (the class itself) is not the same as `FirstClass(name="default_name")` (an instance of that class)

Comment: @9769953 I got perfect answer for my needs from Pranav Hosangadi, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the *type* `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` to define `MAPPER`, but you use an *instance* of those classes to lookup `MAPPER[itr]`. It will work if you use the type instead, like so: `MAPPER[type(itr)]`.

```
for itr in itr_list:
    get_key = MAPPER[type(itr)]
    print(get_key)
```

will output

```
888
999
```