# Python dataclasses: is it safe to use an id-based hash instead of `unsafe_hash=True`?

Tags: python, hash, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass that represents a 2D point:

```
@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
```

I want the `Point` class to have the following behaviour, so that different point objects can be compared based on value, but also stored separately in a dictionary:

```
p1 = Point(5, 10)
p2 = Point(5, 10)

p1 == p2  # Should return True
p1 is p2  # Should return False
hash(p1) == hash(p2)  # Should return False, so that they can be stored as different entries in a dict
```

I could use `unsafe_hash=True`, e.g.

```
@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
```

But this will cause problems when the points are stored in a dictionary. E.g.

```
p1 = Point(5, 10)
p2 = Point(5, 10)

d = {p1: True, p2: False}
d  # Returns {Point(x=5, y=10): False}
```

Is there any reason why I shouldn't instead implement the `__hash__` method to return a hash based on the id of the object? Similar to the implementation of `object.__hash__` ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#:%7E:text=If%20eq%20and,id%2Dbased%20hashing)).

```
@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(id(self))
```

This seems like the simplest solution, and gives the class the desired behaviour, but it seems to go against the advice in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a python dataclass hashable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390576/how-can-i-make-a-python-dataclass-hashable)

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Why do you want two equal objects to have different entries in a dictionary?

Comment: @DainiusPreimantas thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately not. The answer to that question suggests implementing a new `__hash__` method but doesn't go into detail. One of the comments to the answer mentioned using `hash(self.id)`, but this is of course different to `hash(id(self))`

Comment: @PawełRubin - the reason for this is to generate additional data for each point (a bool in my example), and store in a dictionary for quick access (there are a lot of points). There are also many places in my program where the `__eq__` method is useful for `Point`. The point objects are frequently updated, so need to remain mutable, and may be set to the same coordinates as another point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that that `__hash__` goes against the recommendations in the docs. In fact, it's more than a recommendation; Python's built-in data structures are allowed to rely on that assumption. If you have two equal objects which hash to different values, then indexing into a dictionary whose keys are those points could return *either* point, depending entirely on how the dictionary is stored internally. Now, the current Python implementation may or may not actually do this, but other Python implementations could, and a future version of Python might break your code. Bottom line: *It's a bad idea*.

Let me propose a different idea. You want two different things, so consider making two different classes. One class can represent the concrete notion of identity (both in `__hash__` and in `__eq__`, for consistency). Then have a *separate* class for the point-to-point equality.

```
class PointObject:
  point: Point

  def __init__(self, point: Point) -> None:
    self.point = point

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Point:
  x: int
  y: int
```

Now your hash can have `PointObject` as keys, but you can do all of your business logic on the contained `Point` objects. Obviously, you might pick a better name than "PointObject", depending on what they actually represent in your domain model.

Comment: Thanks Silvio! In hindsight, this makes a lot of sense with the wording in the docs. Using your suggestion without frozen (as I need the points to be immutable) and then using the `PointObject`s as keys for the dictionary has worked for me.