# how to make python objects compositions (list objects in list objects)

Tags: python, list, inheritance

I have some 3 layers which are connected by parent - child - sub-child as compositions.
Where the child element depends on the upper parent element (and is destroyed when parent is destroyed).
Like a book, which has several pages, which has several words.
How do i model this correctly?
I want to create them from the inside to outside and the best is to add the 2 childs as a list to the respective parent object.

```
class Book:    
    def __init__(self, bookName):
        self.bookName = bookName
        self.listOfPageObjects = []


class Page(Book):
    pageBackColor = "white"

    def __init__(self, bookName, numberOfWords, pageNumber):
        super().__init__(bookName)
        self.numberOfWords = numberOfWords
        self.pageNumber = pageNumber
        self.listOfWordObjects = []


class Word(Page):
    wordFont = "courier"
    wordMaxLen = 100

    def __init__(self, bookName, numberOfWords, pageNumber, actualWord):
        super().__init__(bookName, numberOfWords, pageNumber)
        self.actualWord = actualWord
```

Would this be the ideal way to do that?

Comment: A page is not a kind of book, nor is a word a kind of page; inheritance is not appropriate here.

Comment: Instead of inheritance, [maybe a data class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes) decorator would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composition means storing a collection of objects inside another object. A very simple example: a `Book` is primarily a list of `Page`s, and a `Page` is primarily a list of `Word`s.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, pages):
        self.book_name = name
        self.pages = pages

class Page:
    def __init__(self, number, words):
        self.number = number
        self.words = words

class Word:
    def __init__(self, word, font="Courier"):
        self.word = word
        self.font = font

pages = [Page(1, [Word("Call"), Word("me"), Word("Ishmael"), ...]),
         Page(2, [...])],
         ...
        ]

b = Book("Moby Dick", pages)
```

Comment: ok thanks for your all input. It is very helpful.
Still 2 questions:
- do you see the need not to do this with a list, but with a dict or something else?
- can somebody give me a link to an clean coded example python software (learn by reading code) of such a use case?