# Is there an iterative method to apply attributes to a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

Hypothetically speaking, assume one has this `class`:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, lastName, firstName, age,):
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.age = age
```

To add other attributes, it would be the same method. However, writing `self.attribute = attribute` would become extremely tiresome after a while, especially if a dozen or more attributes were required, in cases of a larger class.

Is there some way to iteratively apply the variable name to the attribute? Perhaps by setting up a loop and applying the attributes autonomously?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are data classes and how are they different from common classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes)

Comment: It's interesting, but not exactly. I'm looking for more of a for loop answer that would be a one or two liner.

Comment: To set up a loop with attribute names you have to type all those attribute names to loop over.  Using a dataclass does not involve any more typing than setting up that loop. dataclasses were *made* to lessen the tedium of *making* a class.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you drafted a short solution restating what you wrote here I'll mark it off for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module - it reduces the tedium of making a class

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class F:
...     attr1: str
...     attr2: str
...     attr3: str
...     attr4: str
>>> f = F('x','y','z','a')
>>> f
F(attr1='x', attr2='y', attr3='z', attr4='a')
>>> f.attr1
'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have arbitrary logic inside the `__init__` method, at the end of the day it's function. So there's no problem in something like this

```
 class myclass:
      def __init__(self,attributes):
         for att in attributes: self.att = att
```

EDIT: Although this isn't what you are looking for you can try setting the attributes after the init like this

```
atts = dict(#att:value dictionary)
for att,val in atts: setattr(myclass,att,val)
```

Comment: I tried implementing this but got an AttributeError.