# Is there a reason to define non-static class members in class header?

Tags: python

In the example provided by Martijn Pieters in [What are data classes and how are they different from common classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes), he defines some class members in the class header, as well as in `__init__()`:

```py
class InventoryItem:
    '''Class for keeping track of an item in inventory.'''
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0

    def __init__(
            self, 
            name: str, 
            unit_price: float,
            quantity_on_hand: int = 0
        ) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.unit_price = unit_price
        self.quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand
...
```

What is the reason to do that, is it not enough to define them in `__init__()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes#comment83682267_47955313) by [Martijn Pieters♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters):

> there are no class attributes, there are only type annotations. See [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), specifically [the Class and instance variable annotations section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations).

Comment: You can link to a comment, but quoting is always the right approach over posting a link, regardless. Don't forget to attribute the quote properly.

Comment: I didn't know for the link. :-) I forgot about quoting and edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind the same is true for dataclasses; the only difference is that the `dataclass` decorator uses the annotations to generate an `__init__` that does the same thing: initialize instance attributes from arguments.