# Python dictionary with fixed .keys() contents and variable arguments

Tags: python, python-3.9

I'm trying to read in a bunch of data from text files to a dictionary, and I've made a couple of small typos which end up creating new key/value pairs and breaking the program (which can be annoying and a pain to debug).

This got me wondering if there is a way to create a dictionary to which no keys can be added or removed after the initial declaration. This strikes me as something that must exist but I can't find an example of it; does anyone know of something that would fit the bill?

```py
def change_key(dictionary, key, new_value):
    a = dictionary.__len__()
    dictionary[key] = new_value
    if dictionary.__len__() != a:
        raise ValueError("new key added")
```

What I'm looking for is a more elegant implementation of the code above that is:

1. not a massive mess of code
2. capable of dealing with things like appending to a nested list or adding to a nested dict
3. reasonably efficient

Comment: You could create a Function with predefined Keys which just alters the Values inside the Dictionary checking before Insertion if the Key exists

Comment: What would be inmutable keys? Do you mean that you cannot remove or add keys?

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes

Comment: How does an inmutable dict solves your issue? Perhaps you can add a code example to better understand the problem

Comment: Maybe fuzzy string matching could be an option for ignoring typos etc.

Comment: @DaniMesejo rather than having to dig through the program to find the line where I misspelled a key there would be a nice easy error log showing me where and when I did it.

Comment: I'm using this in a relatively big program and the values have to be read, re-assigned and altered a bunch so it can be a pain to track down bugs

Comment: Why you say that the solution in the link `didn't completely prevent alteration`?

Comment: @LW it would work but it seems unnecessarily complicated

Comment: *"if there is a way to create a dictionary with immutable keys but mutable values"* - that's exactly what a dict already is...

Comment: I've personally disliked the comments that were added as they just served to add more fuel to a raging fire; point being, the question is already sufficiently confusing as it stands. Even after re-reading it the first time, I *still* have **no idea** what the question is asking. Please update the question above to clarify better on the specific problem you're having, and how you would like to resolve it; I would personally illustrate with a code example to convey this a bit more clearly.

Comment: @Tomerikoo apologies I meant where the ```__dict__``` is immutable. e.g. you cannot add or remove keys. I have corrected the question

Comment: @AdamLadd that is absolutely not what you mean -- `dict` objects **don't even have `__dict__`'s**. In any case, it sounds like you just want a custom class with `__slots__`

Comment: As an aside, you really shouldn't be doing `dictionary.__len__()` and instead just do `len(dictionary)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga apologies my understanding was that dicts were objects and all objects had ```__dict__```'s so I didn't think to check. I have corrected the question again

Comment: Yes, dicts are objects, but not all objects have `__dict__`. User-defined objects will have a `__dict__` by default *unless* you define `__slots__`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a dataclass with [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059785/11010254) method (In Python 3.10+, this can be achieved with `@dataclass(slots=True)`):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


@dataclass
class FixedKeys:
    __slots__ = ("key_1", "key_2", "key_3")
    key_1: str
    key_2: str
    key_3: str


d = FixedKeys(key_1="something", key_2="something_else", key_3="another_thing")
d.key_1 = "updated_value"  # This will work fine
d.key_that_was_not_predefined = "some value"  # This will raise AttributeError
d = asdict(d)  # This converts a dataclass instance to a normal dictionary
```

Comment: this is good. the question was however not, but this is pretty rock solid, or at least getting there. good work, man!

Comment: Just a regular class will do just fine, and note, `HashMap` is a terrible name for a class that doesn't implement a hash map...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You probably wouldn't want to declare a normal class in situations where all you want is a structure to store some state, as that comes with [large amounts boilerplate dunder method code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47955313/11010254) and requires even more code like a vars() call and a dictionary comprehension to convert to a normal dictionary.