# Canonic way to use Namespaces / Bunchs in Python

Tags: python

This is maybe rather a style-question. Often, I use `dict`s in Python for passing around bundles of variables (like keyword parameters in any function call).

However, my interactive environment (*ipython* or the debugging console in my IDE) does not support `dict`-key autocomplete. This is why I often end up printing out the dict-keys to see whats there.

For me, it seems much more convenient, therefore, to have a simple class, whose instances carry the parameters as attributes (allowing autocomplete in *ipython*). I know this is also called a "Bunch" sometimes, or a perhaps "Namespace" (`argparse.Namespace` seems to be just that, for instance).

I'd dislike writing such a generic thing for myself, if it already exists (grabbing it from `argparse` doesn't seem right, either), so here's the question:

*Is there a supposed way to implement that? Perhaps the standard lib even has something like that?*

Thanks everybody, already!

Comment: A dataclass? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes

Comment: dataclass or namedtuple

Comment: there's a `SimpleNamespace` in the `types` module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of options for cheap class-like things that pass around bundles of variables.

## Namespace Objects

You already mentioned [`argparse.Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace), so I'll mention it as well. Here's how to make a class that lets you store arbitrary fields on it.

```
class Namespace:
  pass
```

Yeah, it's that simple. Now you can make a `Namespace()` and assign arbitrary values to it. Now, `argparse.Namespace` also gives us value equality and a few helpers (such as `__repr__`) that make debugging nice, but that's the basic idea. That being said, you mention your IDE, and I doubt your IDE will be of much help here.

I generally don't recommend namespace classes, since they're just dictionaries disguised as better-structured classes. But the option is there.

## Typed Dict

[`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) isn't a real class. That is, if you use `TypedDict`, then under the hood you're still writing dictionaries just like you are right now. But if your IDE recognizes Python type annotations, then it might start suggesting things in this case.

```
class MyValues(TypedDict):
  name: str
  age: int

my_values: MyValues = {"name": "Steve", "age": 23}
```

Now any static analysis tool knows that `my_values` has specifically an element called `name` of type `str` and an element called `age` of type `int`. Again, this changes *nothing* at runtime, but good static analysis engines will pick up on the hint.

## Named Tuples

For cheap, small collections of variables, [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is your friend. These aren't dictionaries. They're actually tuples, but the fields have names.

```
MyValues = namedtuple('MyValues', ('name', 'age'))
values = MyValues('Steve', 24)
print(values.name) # Steve
print(values.age) # 24
```

Named tuples are *literally* tuples. They'll compare equal to a tuple of the same elements (even if the other tuple isn't named, or is a named tuple of a different type), and they can be destructured, which makes them *very* useful for return values.

```
name, age = function_that_returns_my_values()
```

If you're interested in static typing (and I am firmly of the opinion that you *should* be), you can use [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), which does the same thing but annotates the fields with static types so that a type-checker can validate them. Remember that, as with all static typing in Python, the Python runtime doesn't care about your type annotations, so you need to run additional static analysis for them to be meaningful.

```
class MyValues(NamedTuple):
  name: str
  age: int
```

## Dataclasses

Then we get to the really meaty solution. If you want a real class (i.e. not `TypedDict`) but your data is complicated enough or significant enough that you've outgrown `namedtuple`, then [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) are your best friend. `dataclasses` is your general-purpose "make a structured class with nice behavior out of these fields" decorator.

```
@dataclass
class MyValues:
  name: str
  age: int
```

This generates a class `MyValues` and a *bunch* of nice helpers. It's boilerplate magic for basically this.

```
class MyValues:

  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, MyValues) and (self.name, self.age) == (other.name, other.age)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"MyValues(name={self.name}, age={self.age})"
```

You get an automatic constructor for free, nice value equality, and a pretty printed representation. If you use `@dataclass(frozen=True)` (which I always use as a default), then the fields become immutable and you also get value-based `__hash__`ing.

`dataclass`es are insanely customizable, and I'm not going to go into all the details here. You can read all about them at the module documentation (linked above) or [PEP 557](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/) (which is very readable, despite being a technical standard).

`dataclass`es are my number one recommendation. They get all the benefits of `namedtuple` with none of the weird side effects of being a tuple (and hence being iterable). And all type checkers understand them, since they're built into base Python.

## attrs

If you outgrow even `dataclasses`, then you can look into [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/). This is a library-based solution, so it does incur a dependency. `attrs` is what `dataclasses` was largely inspired by. It can do everything the latter can do, and it can additionally have validators, converters, and all kinds of goodies that make things easier. Start with `dataclasses`, and if you find yourself thinking you need more power, then `attrs` may have you covered, and the migration path is very straightforward.

The only thing of note is the type checking. If you're using static analysis, then type checking is a *bit* more nebulous here than with `dataclasses`, since `attrs` is a library and not built-in to Python. `mypy` ships with a custom plugin that just makes everything work, and in my experience it's *amazing* and handles all of the `attrs` idioms exceedingly well. Other type checkers have more limited support, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Regarding the first option, you don't even need to define `Namespace`; it's essentially already available as `types.SimpleNamespace`. (Though the documentation for that immediately suggests `namedtuple` instead.)

Comment: Thank you - awesome answer! Very interesting read that equips me with a lot of options! :)

Answer (score 1):

The stdlib tool for a simple, generic namespace object would be [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
In [1]: import types

In [2]: x = types.SimpleNamespace(a=1, b=2)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: namespace(a=1, b=2)

In [4]: x.c = 3

In [5]: x
Out[5]: namespace(a=1, b=2, c=3)

In [6]: del x.b

In [7]: x
Out[7]: namespace(a=1, c=3)

In [8]: x.a
Out[8]: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to structure data within Python.  Here are a few in order of increasing rigidity / type safety.

### dict

A `dict` is schema-less; the keys can be any immutable value (e.g., int and tuple, but not a dict), and values can be anything.  These are great for prototyping and when the shape of the data isn't known beforehand, but should be avoided for code interfaces.

```
>>> person_dict = {"first": "John", "last": "Doe", "age": 22}
```

### dict façades

There are several thin [façades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) over dicts that expose keys as properties for convenience. I think this is probably what you're looking for. Since Python 3.3, `SimpleNamespace` is what I'd use for your purpose. Alternatives to this are/were Bunch (from sklearn) and attrdict (no longer developed). These wrappers are also schema-less, so extensible on-the-fly and have no type safety. The dictionary keys must be valid property names.

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> person_sn = SimpleNamespace(**person_dict)
>>> person_sn
namespace(first='John', last='Doe', age=22)
>>> person_sn.first
'John'
>>> person_sn.height_cm = 183  # dynamically add to structure
>>> person_sn.__dict__
{'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'age': 22, 'height_cm': 183}
```

Although you could use argparse's Namespace class, I see no reason to co-opt that when SimpleNamespace is available.

### schema-based structures

Schema-based structures are useful for interfaces where (weak) type safety, validation, or inheritance are desired.  Python's [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/), and [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/) use named classes and schemas to validate data.

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass(slots=True)
... class Person:
...     first: str
...     last: str
...     age: int
... 
>>> person_dc = Person(**person_dict)
>>> person_dc.first
'John'
>>> person_dc.height_cm = 183
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[20], line 1
    person_dc.height_cm = 183
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'height_cm'
```